# What is the difference between Leaflet and Mapbox?

Tags: web-mapping, leaflet, mapbox

What is the difference between Leaflet and Mapbox, and how are they used together?
Like the API and what exactly are they and is Mapbox using Leaflet?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. I suggest you take a look at these two links. Mapbox is not specifically addressed in either, but they do contain info on Leaflet and many other APIs. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8032/comparison-of-javascript-mapping-libraries  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13868/looking-for-a-developer-friendly-web-gis  Hopefully someone will answer here with more info on Mapbox

Comment: thx for the answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Leaflet is a Javascript Map Client API - it requests images from services like MapBox and provides the panning / zooming experience you'd see in Google Maps or similar. You'd use the two together - MapBox provides tiles of maps, and Leaflet makes them usable in web pages.