# Open source vs Proprietary

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the FOSS equivalents to these ArcGIS products?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13171/what-are-the-foss-equivalents-to-these-arcgis-products)

'm especially interested in Open Source vs Proprietary decisions. Can any of the open source software for database management substitute ArcGIS for Server?.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it can.

Take a look on the [Postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org/) / [Postgis](http://postgis.refractions.net/) solution.